# CSS Styling LI and A tags with FORM inside LI

Tags: css, forms, html-lists

I am having some difficulty styling an A tag when embedded into a FORM as the example below follows. I would like to LI > FORM > A to look the same as LI > FORM > A:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "Manage", "Account")</li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><form><a href="">Log Off</a></form></li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS I have is from Twitter Bootstrap. Here is the CSS I would expect to work...but doesn't stylize the FORM A tag:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > form > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > form > a:focus,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: EDIT:  I would like to LI > FORM > A to look the same as LI > A:

Comment: You should [edit] your post with corrections instead of placing them in comments. The link is below the tags for the post

Comment: I also can't duplicate your problem. If I run this code it does change the color on hover & focus.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have problem stylizing it on or out of hover? On hover, I can't see any problems.. If you have problem when out of hover, you could do something like:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a,
.dropdown-menu > li > form > a{
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```